# Finding the minimum value above 0 in a 2D array. Python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to find  the minimum value in a 2D array greater than 0. I've looked at the solutions given for the 1D case, and tried to apply that to this particular situation, but I get nothing out.

```
count1
Out[36]: 
array([[2787, 2748, 2752, ..., 2820, 2832, 2903],
       [2794, 2729, 2748, ..., 2810, 2811, 2872],
       [2785, 2796, 2773, ..., 2852, 2877, 2854],
       ...,
       [2833, 2713, 2692, ..., 2703, 2883, 2974],
       [2759, 2726, 2688, ..., 2779, 2863, 2893],
       [2802, 2755, 2637, ..., 2777, 2841, 2946]], dtype=uint16)

k =0

a = np.min(filter(lambda x: x>k,count1))

a
Out[39]: <filter at 0x1a56f9dbc88>
```

For reason I don't know of, instead of getting actual values, I get the filter message. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try ```count1[count1>k].min()```

Comment: You can use .flatten() to flatten an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a numpy array, a much simpler way to filter and get the minimum is to do the following.

```
np.min(count1[count1>k])
```

And the reason you see a filter object is that `filter` returns a filter object. Also, I am not very sure if `filter` works with 2D arrays. You might have to first flatten it if you want to use `filter`

Comment: I'm not sure why that has been down voted, but it did exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: It was downvoted because it gave the answer without an explanation. Such answers are rarely useful to the community in general. I have removed my downvote now that an explanation was added.

Answer (score 1):

[`filter`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_filter.asp) returns an iterable. You need to iterate over the iterables to get the values. This would work:

```
filtered = [f for f in filter(lambda x: x > 0, count1)]
a = np.min(filtered)
```

Or a better idea would be to use boolean indexing in numpy. For example,

```
filter = count1 > 0
filtered = count1[filter]
a = np.min(filtered)
```

Or you could combine them into one statement

```
a = np.min(count1[count1 > 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

First, you need to flatten your 2D matrix before sending into a lambda function if you're just looking for the minimum element. Otherwise, it is trying to evaluate the entire row.

Second, the reason you are getting the filter message is because you haven't yet evaluated the filter. Use `list` to evaluate `filter`.

```
count1 = np.random.randint(0,2000,size=(20,20))
k = 0

a = list(filter(lambda x: x>k,count1.flatten()))
print(np.min(a))
```

As the other answer indicates, I would approach this problem by numpy logicals like so:

```
np.min(count1[count1>k])
```